# inserir sequencia de data no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Quando inserir a data no for ele soma + 1 dia e insere novamente.

alguma ideia ?

```
$valores = range(1,5);
$date = '2016-02-06';                            

            for ( $i = 0, $total = count($valores); $i < $total;  $i++){


            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `lancamentos`(equip,plan,real,data) values(?,?,?,?)';
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $q->execute(array($e1,$p1,$r1,$data));            

           $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day" strtotime($data)));



                }
```

Comment: Não compreendi a sua pergunta... Dê mais detalhes do que você desejar fazer.

Comment: Explique melhor a sua dúvida!
Se o que eu entendi está correto você quer que a cada laço do for ele adicione mais um dia na sua data, correto?
Se for isso passe a variável $i no lugar de ("+1 days").
Ficando da seguinte forma strtotime($i . " days", strtotime($data));

Comment: é isso mesmo, vou testar aqui, obrigado.

Comment: estava pulando alguns dias não ficou sequencial, mais adicionei uma variável para fazer, graças ao seu exemplo, agradeço pela ajuda, ajudou muito aqui, obrigado!